# Why Ionic 1 Media Plugin Error {"code" : 1} after playing N times? (android)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-media-plugin

I know this is strange, but this is my observation:

I managed to play some music with the Media Plugin in Ionic 1 using:

```
//Method 1: just plugin
mediaRes = new Media(myMusicPath, onMediaSuccess, onMediaError, onMediaStatus);

//Method 2: ngCordova
mediaRes = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(myMusicPath)
mediaRes.play().then(onMediaSuccess, onMediaError, onMediaStatus);
```

As read from other posts, the path is crucial:

```
"/android_asset/www/music/mymusic.mp3"
```

Basically the path name has been printed on my HTML so it won't be wrong.

For the first N times, it works properly. Then, on the (N + 1)th, it fails with error `{"code":1}.`

Why this happens? Do I need to somehow clear cache or something before re-initializing the variable? Currently I re-initialize the variable every time i run it.

**EDIT:**

Seems that it is OK to play infinitely if I just perform `'play()'` without re-initializing the same variable again. Would continue observing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `release()`
>
> Releases the underlying operating system’s audio resources. This is
>   particularly important for Android, since there are a finite amount of
>   OpenCore instances for media playback. Applications should call the
>   release function for any Media resource that is no longer needed.

Apparently, the `release` function is required. And that solves the problem.